# Get an error when I try to run manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to start a project in Django and I installed everything according to the documentation here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Now, when I try to run the server with the command "py manage.py runserver", I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I have added all the required environment variables and I can't figure out what's the issue here. Any help would be great! :)

Comment: ```pip install django```. if you are having a ```virtual env``` then activate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you install your virtual environment

```
py -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win

workon myvenv

python -m venv myvenv
```

Make sure you are in correct directory to load your virtual environment

```
PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb>  . myvenv\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

You will know when its activated it will look similar to this (myvenv)
Then install Django via pip like so

```
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb> pip install django
```

create your project and cd into

```
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb> django-admin startproject myproject
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb> ls
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb> cd myproject
```

to run local server the folder path should line up

```
(myvenv) PS C:\Users\taylo\Desktop\django-project\myweb\myproject> python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Try command " python manage.py runserver" to run the server. check if django is installed or not use the command "pip freeze" to check all python package installed.
If you installed djanjo in virtalenv check virtualenv activated or not?

Comment: It was to do with the virtual environment not being set up. It's fixed now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  that django is installed on your system.

`py -m django`

If that command leads you to error `"No moduled named django"`, try the command:

`py -m pip install django`

Comment: It was to do with the virtual environment in this case, it's all fixed now, thanks for the help!